# What does an escaped ampersand mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, escaping, lexer

I looked at the [Haskell 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17700010.2) report and noticed a weird escape sequence with an ampersand: `\&`. I couldn't  find an explanation what this escape sequence should stand for. It also might only be located in strings. I tried `print "\&"` in GHCi, and it prints an empty string.

Comment: It’s an empty escape for breaking up other meaningful sequences. I don’t remember exactly what it lets you write – `"\012\&3"` or something?

Comment: The explanation you seek is [in section 2.6, Character and String Literals](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-200002.6).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It escapes... no character. It is useful to "break" some escape sequences. For instance 
we might want to express `"\12" ++ "3"` as a single string literal. If we try the obvious approach, we get

```
"\123" ==> "{"
```

We can however use

```
"\12\&3"
```

for the intended result.

Also, `"\SOH"` and `"\SO"` are both valid single ASCII character escapes, making `"\SO" ++ "H"` tricky to express as a single literal: we need `"\SO\&H"` for that.

This escape trick is also exploited by the standard `Show String` instance, which has to produce a valid literal syntax. We can see this in action in GHCi:

```
> "\140" ++ "0"
"\140\&0"
> "\SO" ++ "H"
"\SO\&H"
```

Further, this greatly helps external programs which aim to generate Haskell code (e.g. for metaprogramming). When emitting characters for a string literal, the external program can add `\&` at the end of potentially ambiguous escapes (or even of all escapes) so that the program does not have to handle unwanted interactions. E.g. if the program wants to emit `\12` now, it can emit `\12\&` and be free to emit anything as the next character. Otherwise, the program should remember that, when the next character is emitted, it has to be prepended by `\&` if it's a digit. It's simpler to always add `\&`, even if it's not needed: `\12\&A` is legal, and has the same meaning as `\12A`.

Finally, a quote from the Haskell Report, explaining `\&`:

> 2.6  Character and String Literals
>
> [...]
>
> Consistent with the "maximal munch" rule, numeric escape characters in strings consist of all consecutive digits and may be of arbitrary length. Similarly, the one ambiguous ASCII escape code, `"\SOH"`, is parsed as a string of length 1. The escape character `\&` is provided as a `"null character"` to allow strings such as `"\137\&9"` and `"\SO\&H"` to be constructed (both of length two). Thus `"\&"` is equivalent to `""` and the character `'\&'` is disallowed. Further equivalences of characters are defined in Section 6.1.2.

Comment: It’s also the zero-width equivalent of a *gap*: a backslash followed by some whitespace and another backslash is stripped from the string to allow multi-line string literals, but with no intervening whitespace this gives a single backslash. I’ve found it useful to help syntax highlighters that get tripped up on gaps at the end of a string, since the literal ends with `\"` but that’s not an escaped quotation mark.